# Core Data: using undefined transient attribute

Tags: ios, ios4, core-data

I am trying to use an Undefined attribute that is also Transient. The attribute is of type ABRecordRef (which isn't even an object in Objective-C), and I can get the object by using the ABRecordID, which is an int32 that I persist in my model.

I made the getter pretty easily:

```
- (ABRecordRef) abRecordPerson
{
    ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(book, [self.abGlobalID intValue]);
    return record;
}
```

This works fine, till I try to save a new object:

```
Person *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    newManagedObject.abGlobalID = [NSNumber numberWithInt: recordID];
    //newManagedObject.abRecordPerson = person;
```

I get a crash whether I have the last line commented out or not. If it's commented out, it gives me this error:

> Unresolved error Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (Cocoa error 1570.)"
>   UserInfo=0xe0138c0
>   {NSValidationErrorObject= (entity: Person; id:
>   0xc611e10
>   
>   ; data: {
>       abGlobalID = 6;
>       abRecordPerson = nil; })

It seems to think abRecordPerson is nil, so I tried to set it, but then I get this error:

> CoreData: error: Property
>   'setAbRecordPerson:' is a scalar type
>   on class 'Person' that does not match
>   its Entity's property's scalar type. 
>   Dynamically generated accessors do not
>   support implicit type coercion. 
>   Cannot generate a setter method for
>   it. 
>   2011-06-21 20:07:18.100
>   TestCoreDataLab[79616:207] -[Person
>   setAbRecordPerson:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6d10f40

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've defined the getter `-abRecordPerson`, but have you created a `-setAbPersonRecord`? The error seems to indicate that you haven't, and it looks like that's the root of the problem.

Comment: I had, but had some issue due to iOS5. Turns out, after figuring that issue out, the setter does work.